# How to catch key states when I am dragging an object over a control? - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, cursor, keydown

I need to change drag&drop effects with some keys while I am dragging some text inside a listbox.

```
bool ctrlD = false;

private void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        ctrlD = true;
}

// KeyUp 

private void textBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    textBox.DoDragDrop(textBox.Text, DragDropEffects.All);
}

private void listBox_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (ctrlD) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    else e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}
```

The problem is DragOver method doesn't see when any keys are pressed. Effects don't change. What can I do to this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.querycontinuedrag(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Hans Passant I still can't understand how to change cursor effects. QueryContinueDrag doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

```
bool ctrlD = false
```

> Use object sender

```
private void textBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
      this.DoDragDrop(sender, DragDropEffects.All);
    }
}
```

> Make sure to set AllowDrop to True
>
> > Add (MyContol) (_DragEnter) and (_DragDrop) events

```
private void MyControl_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    /*
    DragDropEffects
    */
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy; 
}

private void MyControl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = e.Data.GetData(typeof(TextBox)) as TextBox;
    /*
    MyControl.Controls.Add(tb);
    * Your code here
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the DragEventArgs within your listBox_DragOver event to know what buttons and keys have been used for the drag operation:

```
    if ((e.KeyState & 32) == 32) { bool alt = true; }
    if ((e.KeyState & 16) == 16) { bool mousebuttonmiddle = true; }
    if ((e.KeyState & 8) == 8) { bool control = true; }
    if ((e.KeyState & 4) == 4) { bool shift = true; }
    if ((e.KeyState & 2) == 2) { bool mousebutton2 = true; }
    if ((e.KeyState & 1) == 1) { bool mousebutton1 = true; }
```